# Microsoft Web Helpers and Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using **MVC3 with Razor.**

I have installed the **microsoft-web-helpers package through Nuget.**

I have declared this code **@Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId**

I'm getting an error for **'FacebookApplication'.**

Error message; **'Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Facebook' does not contain a definition for 'FacebookApplication'**

Any workaround for this?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding FB functionality Microsoft.Web.Helpers API doesn't provide anything more than a LikeButton method to render the button, based on the passed parameters.

If you are creating a FB application/game and want a C# library please have a look at [Facebook C# SDK](http://docs.csharpsdk.org/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am trying to implement a FB login button from this link; http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2011/09/19/facebook-login-integration/
Failing miserably though due to the FBApplication error

Comment: If you're just after FB login button, the easiest way would be to use FB JavaScript SDK: [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login). I assume you've already created a new app and have both AppID and secret handy.